# ranger regression with interaction, then predict - ind. variables not found

Tags: r, random-forest, r-ranger

I'm using the R package 'ranger' to make a regression random forest.  The predictors (aka independent variables)  include some interaction terms.  When I ask the model to predict with some new data (exact same columns as training data), it complains: `Error in predict.ranger.forest(forest, data, predict.all, num.trees, type,  : Error: One or more independent variables not found in data.`

Do I have to somehow create the interactions in the validation/prediction dataset?  I don't know how.  This doesn't make sense.

Example:

```
df <- data.frame( p1=1:10, p2=3:12, response=11:20)
train <- df[ 1:5, ]
valid <- df[ 6:10, ]
regr <- ranger( data = train, formula = response ~ p1 + p2 + p1*p2 )
pred <- predict( object=regr, data=valid )
```

Comment: The problem I see is a complete lack of overlap of the values for p1 and p2 in the train and predict datasets. How are you supposed to "predict" based on values that were not in the range of the original data?

Comment: @IRTFM, I just separated training and validation simply.  In a real regression it should be done randomly.  But that actually has nothing to do with it.  You get the same error with train <- df[ c( 1,3,5,7,9,10 ), ] and valid <- df[ c( 2,4,6,8 ), ].

Comment: I'm getting strange results using that code applied to the non-interaction model. The predictions for valid are 13 and the predictions for the train set are all near the mean. I'm not sure that this toy data is supporting regression-like description or inference. I'm wondering how mature this package is and whether it's intended for typical "regression". It doesn't seem to have much in the way of worked examples, and I haven't found any code examples of is use in estimating regression coefficients. The documentation says it estimates adjusted means rather than regression coefficients.

Comment: If you have a citation that's more focused on the "regression" mode of this package. I'd be happy to read it and attempt application of my modest skills at digging into the code to see if there's feasibility to specify interaction terms in its formula interface.

Comment: Re strange results, when I use no interaction term and the revised train/valid sets in my previous comment, my 'valid' predictions are 12.9, 13.4, 15.4, 18.1.  That's not far off the actual response in valid.  But I probably shouldn't have used a made-up dataset as it kind of sidetracked the discussion.  I now believe that predict() cannot use interaction terms unless they are given as columns in the train and valid data.  i.e., df$inter <- df$p1 * df$p2, then train with the formula "response ~ p1+p2+inter"

Comment: Agree. That avoids the difficulty in getting the predict code to properly handle a "special" coefficient that might or might not be "p1:p2" which is how it gets recorded in the trained result object. I remain puzzled after reading in more than one place that random_forest methods are reputedly able to detect interactions without any prompting encoded within the formula.